# IllegalStateException: AlertDialog, onClick, ThemeWrapper

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting couple of problems regarding my onClick button on my TextView. In my code, I am making alertDialog to show up when there is an onClick event. However, the app is force closing:

This is **ProfilePage.java**

```
package com.tanishqsharma.unanswered.BackgroundProcesses;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tanishqsharma.unanswered.R;
import com.tanishqsharma.unanswered.dbHandler.PrefManager;


import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfilePage extends Activity {

    //UI elements
    TextView userMobile;
    TextView userName;
    Button updateButton;

    String mobile;
    String name;
    PrefManager prefManager;
    CircleImageView profile_image;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);

        userMobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userMobile);
        userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
        updateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
        profile_image = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());


        mobile = "+91 "+prefManager.getUserMobile();
        name = prefManager.getUserName();


        //Setting Up Name
        if(name.equals(""))
        {
            userName.setText("Enter Your Name");
        }
        else
        {
            userName.setText(name);
        }


        //Setting Up Mobile Display Button
        userMobile.setText(mobile);
        userMobile.setEnabled(false);


    }


    public void editNameDialogue(View v)
    {
        //This shows the dialogue box which sets the text to the name textview

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogue = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editing_name, null);
        builder.setView(dialogue);

        final EditText entered_name = (EditText)dialogue.findViewById(R.id.edited_name);

        builder.setMessage("Entered Name");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String newName = entered_name.getText().toString();
                userName.setText(newName);
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.create();
        builder.show();

    }

    public void selectDP(View view)
    {
        //This will select DP and set it to the CircularImageView waiting to be transfered to the server.
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Lets select DP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void updateDetails(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Nothing Right Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //This will send everything to the server and preference manager.
        //And send to the main activity
    }


}
```

This is the error:

```
05-29 21:39:13.622 15754-15754/com.tanishqsharma.unanswered E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tanishqsharma.unanswered, PID:15754 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick                                                                   at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4463)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5209)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4458)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5209) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:918)
at com.tanishqsharma.unanswered.BackgroundProcesses.ProfilePage.editNameDialogue(ProfilePage.java:91)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4458) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5209) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21185) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Apparently, `R.style.AlertDialogCustom` is not based on an `AppCompat` theme.

Comment: How do I rectify it? Just replace it with any other from the list?

Comment: I changed it to R.style.app, but another problem which occurs is this:                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: @TanishqSharma: "How do I rectify it?" -- you created `R.style.AlertDialogCustom`. You need to have it inherit from a `Theme.AppCompat`-based theme, such as `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`.

Comment: I replaced it with my theme, however, the problem I am having right now is: `Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: Rectified! Thanks a ton again @CommonsWare. The problem was using ContextWrapper was irrelevant.

Comment: @TanishqSharma: I do not know why your `ContextThemeWrapper` is wrapping `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.